# Match single double quotes, but not if contraction or possession

Tags: regex

There are plenty of questions about matching single and double quotes, but I cannot find one that then excludes contractions and possession marks.

Here are the examples I am using to show matches on regex101.com

```
" I'm not going, so won't you go instead? "
"Hi", 'I can't go!'
I'm not going, so won't you go 'instead'?
O'Connell's bar is "good"
O'Connells' bar is 'excellent'
```

So far, `/(?!\b["']\b)["']/gm` is the best I can create, but this falls short in that it still matches the final `Connells'` which it shouldn't.

I've tried adding more negative lookahead and lookbehind, even asked gpt4 to have a go (and it failed 10 times before I gave up asking it)

My best regex is saying, match single or double quotes but not if found in a word. How can I add another negative saying, and not if found at the end of a word ending is s (i.e. plural possession)

Comment: Maybe `(?!\b'\b)["'](?<!s.\B)`? See https://regex101.com/r/COLA6h/1

Comment: This isn't something you can do with a regular expression. If you see `girls'` how do you expect to tell whether that's a possessive or the end of a quote? You need some kind of natural language processing that understands the context.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there's a good way to distinguish possessive plurals from ending single quotes without doing some kind of parity check. Wiktor's pattern gets around it by making an exception for the letter s, but that of course will lead to issues when you have a word that ends with s surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Your `'I can't go!'` example IMO stands in the way of a solution that matches single quotes.

Comment: I see there are some issues I had not considered, so thanks for responses, but @WiktorStribiżew does give a solution which work as requested for current situation. However I see no way to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @macasas That was a suggestion, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: there is no way for a regex to tell a Possessive case apostrophe from a closing single quote, `'The boys' room'` will be ambiguous.

Answering the current question, namely  the "not if found at the end of a word ending is `s`" part, you can add a `(?<!s.\B)` negative lookbehind at the end of the regex.

Also, since you only want to match a single or double quote and exclude a `'` in between word chars, I suggest removing the `"` from the lookahead (unless you also think the `"` can appear in between word chars, but I can't think of real life scenarios. It can denote an inch and then it is just follows a digit, and you'd need to exclude `(?<=\d)"` then).

So, currently, the update pattern can look like

```
(?!\b'\b)["'](?<!s.\B)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/COLA6h/1). *Details*:

- `(?!\b'\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a `'` char enclosed with letters/digits/underscores
- `["']` - a `'` or `"` char
- `(?<!s.\B)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location (that is, location in the string right after `'` or `"`), there is an `s` + the matched char (`'` or `"` can both be matched with a `.`, it is the simplest pattern to use, but you surely can repeat `['"]`, but I see no reason for it), and then a non-word boundary is required, i.e. after `'` and `"`, there can only be a non-word char or the end of the string.

And there is a more efficient way to write it with two lookbehinds:

```
["'](?<!s.\B)(?<!\b'\b)
```

But if you cannot use lookbehinds, you can also use two lookaheads (making it much more inefficient):

```
(?!\b'\b)(?<!s(?=.\B))["']
```